# What material is used to fill cracks in wood that looks black afterward?

Tags: wood, woodworking, furniture, wooden-furniture

When looking in the more stylish furniture shops, they often have very large tables (e.g. 10cm thick x 1m wide x 2-3m long, made from one piece of lumber.

Understandably, such pieces often have come cracks, etc. In all the shops I went to, I have seen these filled with some black epoxy-like substance, and I liked the way it looked - I would like to use the same to fill cracks in my projects.

What materials can you recommend as wood filler that would give this look?

Answer (score 3):

In many cases that *is* epoxy, mixed with lamp black or another colorant. (There are tints which can be used to more closely match the color of the surrounding wood, but in fact black usually looks pretty reasonable.)

Answer (score 2):

There's a good product that I have used before called 'Ronseal Multipurpose Wood Filler Tub - Dark' you can pick it up for about £6 from the likes of Homebase etc. It gives a nice finish to fill the wood cracks and it dries dark. Can also be used for exterior furniture